# 503 Service Unavailable only when a particular URL is accessed from the terminal command line tools like cUrl or wget

Tags: proxy, wget, https, http-proxy, http-status-codes

I am behind a proxy in a corporate environment:

```
$ printenv  | grep proxy
http_proxy=http://aproxy.corproot.net:8080/
https_proxy=http://aproxy.corproot.net:8080/
```

and trying to access the following 2 URLs from the terminal using `wget` or `curl` (there resources are **not accessible from the Internet**):

- `https://artifactory.swisscom.com/api/npm/npm-remote/npm/-/npm-5.1.0.tgz`
- `https://artifactory.swisscom.com/api/npm/npm-remote/npm/-/npm-5.10.0.tgz`

The first one returns **503 Service Unavailable** while the 2nd returns 200 and the file is downloaded.

When accessed from web browsers on the same computer (with the same HTTP/S proxy set), both URLs are downloading the file (in any browser: Chrome, Firefox, Safari). Also my colleagues with the same OS version (macOS Catalina 10.15.6) and with the same proxy settings like me, can download (`wget` or `curl`) both files from the terminal.

So it cannot be a server error on the side of Artifactory or a proxy error. There must be a configuration on my side that breaks the access to the `npm-5.1.0.tgz` URL.

What could be the issue on my system or how can I troubleshoot it such that I determine what the issue can be?

The result I get when I access the `npm-5.1.0.tgz` URL in the terminal is:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>ICAP Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>ICAP Error (icap_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
An error occurred while performing an ICAP operation: File decompression/decode error; File: npm-5.1.0.tgz; Sub File: ; Vendor: Sophos, Plc.; Engine version: 3.79.0; Pattern version: 5.77.53271598.0; Pattern date: 2020/09/03 08:28:38
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
There could be a network problem, the ICAP service may be misconfigured, or the ICAP server may have reported an error.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<BR>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Transaction ID: c096ba71d6c6f520-00000001bb135417-000000005f50eafc
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.<br><br>Your request was categorized by Blue Coat Web Filter as 'Technology/Internet'. <br>If you wish to question or dispute this result, please click <a href="http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp?referrer=136&url=https://artifactory.swisscom.com/api/npm/npm-remote/npm/-/npm-5.1.0.tgz">here</a>.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The difference between the successful URL (`npm-5.10.0.tzg`) and the failing URL (`npm-5.1.0.tgz`) is also visible in Wireshark (a network inspector tool):

Successful URL (TCP FIN):

[image]

Failing URL (Encrypted Alert and TCP RST:

[image]

Comment: I am located in the US (Brooklyn, NY) and I can’t even ping `artifactory.swisscom.com`.

Comment: `artifactory.swisscom.com/` not accessible.

Comment: The resources in this post are in a corporate environment and hence not accessible from the Internet.